# How to create a while loop that keeps going until 5 variables all equal 10

Tags: while-loop

```py
import random

damage_1 = random.randint(1, 10)
damage_2 = random.randint(1, 10)
damage_3 = random.randint(1, 10)
damage_4 = random.randint(1, 10)
damage_5 = random.randint(1, 10)

entries = 0

while damage_1 != 10 and damage_2 != 10 and damage_3 != 10 and damage_4 != 10 and damage_5 != 10:
  entries = entries + 1
  print(entries)
  print(damage_1)
  print(damage_2)
  print(damage_3)
  print(damage_4)
  print(damage_5)
```

The while loop should keep adding to the **entries** var until all **damage_X** vars equal 10.

Answer (score 0):

You should first initialize all the variables to 0 and then randomly generate them in the while loop.

```
import random
damage_1 = damage_2 = damage_3 = damage_4 = damage_5 = 0
entries = 0
while damage_1 != 10 and damage_2 != 10 and damage_3 != 10 and damage_4 != 10 and damage_5 != 10:
    entries = entries + 1
    print(entries)
    damage_1 = random.randint(1, 10)
    damage_2 = random.randint(1, 10)
    damage_3 = random.randint(1, 10)
    damage_4 = random.randint(1, 10)
    damage_5 = random.randint(1, 10)
    print(damage_1)
    print(damage_2)
    print(damage_3)
    print(damage_4)
    print(damage_5)
```

It should be like this. But you have not mentioned where you are stuck.

Comment: ahh sorry, I'm new to the platform. So the issue is that I want the program to keep looping until all 5 variables = 10, and then it will append the entries variable with how many loops it took for all of the damage variables to equal 10. So far, the code only runs until 10 is found once.

Comment: @AlexanderFord In that case use "or" instead of "and". Loop will break when all values will become equal to 10 whereas in case of "and" it will break if at least one value becomes 10.

Comment: It's correct that you must random the damage_X variables inside the while loop but the chance that all 5 variables will be 10 at the same time is almost nil. To accomplish what he seeks is to add a verification inside the while that first checks if the damage_X variable equals 10 and if not then generate new random and assign to damage_X. Like that the damage_X variables that already equaled 10 will not be assigned a new random value again.

Answer (score 0):

So to accomplish what you want, keep looping and add **1** to **entries** until all **damage_X** variables equal **10**:

```py
import random
damage_1 = damage_2 = damage_3 = damage_4 = damage_5 = 0
entries = 0
while damage_1 != 10 or damage_2 != 10 or damage_3 != 10 or damage_4 != 10 or damage_5 != 10:
    entries += 1
    print(entries)
    if damage_1 != 10: damage_1 = random.randint(1, 10)
    if damage_2 != 10: damage_2 = random.randint(1, 10)
    if damage_3 != 10: damage_3 = random.randint(1, 10)
    if damage_4 != 10: damage_4 = random.randint(1, 10)
    if damage_5 != 10: damage_5 = random.randint(1, 10)
    print(damage_1)
    print(damage_2)
    print(damage_3)
    print(damage_4)
    print(damage_5)
    print("")
```

So you should check if **damage_X** equals **10** and only if it does not assign a new random integer to it. If you do not add that if check, your loop will run for a very long time since the chance that all 5 **damage_X** variables will equal **10** at the same time is extremely low. I did change the **and** to **or** in the while statement cause if you use **and**, the while loop will stop if **one** of the **damage_X** variables equals **10**.